# Error handling to avoid application crash JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In this exercise, you need to handle the error to avoid the application crash.

What does this mean??? I should put a try catch block whithin the function??? I have no idea how to handle the error to avoid the application crash. This is the code I should change:

```
class BankAccount {
  #amount = 0;

  constructor(initialAmount) {
    this.#amount = initialAmount;
  }

  deposit(amount) {
    if (amount < 0) {
      throw new Error('The amount provided cannot be negative');
    }

    this.#amount += amount;
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    if (amount < 0) {
      throw new Error('The amount provided cannot be negative');
    }

    if (this.#amount < amount) {
      throw new Error('You cannot withdraw more than account balance');
    }

    this.#amount -= amount;
  }

  view() {
    console.log(this.#amount);
  }
}

// Handle errors to avoid app crash
const bankAccount = new BankAccount(1000);
bankAccount.deposit(500);
bankAccount.deposit(200);
bankAccount.withdraw(10000);
bankAccount.view();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `try/catch` is no harm for your logic, BUT you need to handle error logs properly. For example,

```
try {
   const bankAccount = new BankAccount(1000);
   bankAccount.deposit(500);
   bankAccount.deposit(200);
   bankAccount.withdraw(10000);
   bankAccount.view();
} catch(error) {
   //TODO: send your error logs to a logging system to track what's happening with your app
}
```

Comment: What's a logging system?

Comment: A logging system is a server to capture all your errors and organize them in good view. That will help us a lot in seeing and debugging errors. Here is one of examples https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/ (Sentry)